# Querying computed fields in GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql, grails-orm

I am trying to query the following HQL using GORM:

```
MailMessage.executeQuery("toId, count(toId) from (SELECT  toId, threadId FROM MailMessage as m WHERE receiveStatus = 'u' GROUP BY threadId, toId) as x group by x.toId")
```

The problem is that `count(toId)` is a computed field doesn't exist in `MailMessage` and that I am using a subquery.

I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!`  Ideally, I would like to use a generic executeQuery which will return data of anytype.  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question.  The only way to do this is to execute raw SQL and not use HQL.  Unfortunately, there is no way that I figured out how to execute a complicated query with a subquery and computed field.

I used the example here: [Grails query not using GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600729/grails-query-not-using-gorm)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this also with criteria builder. [Using groupProperty and countDistinct in Grails Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720060/using-groupproperty-and-countdistinct-in-grails-criteria)

Edith:
Ok you have to mix hibernate criteria into the criteria builder. For subqueries you have to use [org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-creating).

At first you have to create the subquery:

```
 DetachedCriteria avgWeight = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Cat.class)
.setProjection( Property.forName("weight").avg() );
```

If I'm right than you can use it into the criteria builder:

```
Cat.withCriteria{
   and{Subqueries.geAll("weight", weights)}
}
```

Comment: The example you listed is querying from one table (the Transaction table).  In the query above, I am querying from a subquery not a table.  Can you write the Criteria for this in grails?  I simplied the query above, in my real app the query is more complicated and has two nested subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear - what data type are you expecting to get?

If you want just a datatset - list of field value lists, you need to use full HQL "select" syntax, [executeQuery has some examples of](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html).

It looked like you wished to get a collection of `MailMessage`-s with an extra `countToId` field. That's not doable straightforward way, unless you could add dummy field to `MailMessage` and write an 'select' expression for it.

Comment: count(XXX) should return number field.

Comment: :D What whole dataset type you expect in Groovy? `Collection<MailMessage>` or `Collection<Collection<Object>>`?

Comment: [[]] is what I was expecting, but I would accept [[:]]. For example: [[1223, 5], [14455,3], [1111, 4]].  Each subarray is a row in the result set.

Comment: If you write a full statement, starting with `select`, it will return List<List>, try it.