# Grails query not using GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

What is the best way to query for something without using GORM in grails?

I have query that doesn't *seem* to fit in the GORM model, the query has a subquery and a computed field.  I posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577379/quering-computed-fields-in-gorm) already with no response so I decided to take a different approach.  I want to query for something not using GORM within a grails application.  Is there an easy way to get the connection and go through the result set?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In a service or controller, you can add a dependency injection for the `dataSource` bean and use groovy.sql.Sql or JDBC directly if you're a masochist.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class DataService {

   def dataSource

   void runQuery(...) {
      def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      sql.eachRow('select * from foo') { row ->
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the moste cases I use criteria queries.

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
    or {
        like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
        like("holderFirstName", "Barney%")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't support subqueries from what I Know

Comment: @Tihon  it supportet subqueries because it is a hibernate-criteria-query http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries

Comment: @Igs GORM is not criteriaquery. Criteria query looks more like GROM than HSQL but it is not the same. GROM is using meta methodes and criteria queries will use hibernate criteria queries.

Comment: Interesting.  How would you do it in groovy?  The answer is more appropriate on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577379/quering-computed-fields-in-gorm  If you answer it there, I will give you the correct answer.