# How to get DataSource connection from a Groovy Class with this groovy code?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, datasource

I used to have a Java Class in my Grails app, but I needed to get a connection from `DataSource.groovy` so I passed it to a Groovy Class, and I made it getting the Context Application. But How can I connect to that that Datasource with this code?:

```
def dataSource = ctx.getBean('dataSource_Executer') // auto injected and referenced to a datasource
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
Class.forName('driver');
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dataSource);// Here it's the trouble
```

I need it like this because I need the Metadata of the result query like this:

```
 stmt = conn.createStatement();
 def rs = stmt.executeQuery('query');
 def rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 num = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

and control it with a While:

```
 while(rs.next()){..........}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600729/grails-query-not-using-gorm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `groovy.sql` package to do this.

```
import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
import groovy.sql.Sql

def dataSource = ctx.getBean('dataSource_Executer')
def connection = new Sql(dataSource)
def results = connection.rows('SELECT ...')
results.each { r ->
  println r['columnName']
  ...
}
```

You can also access the `ResultSetMetaData` as well. This [blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-access.html) has a good example of how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use auto-wiring in a service/controller:

```
class SomeService {

 DataSource dataSource

 @Transactional
 def someMethod( params = [:] ){
   Sql db = new Sql( dataSource )
   db.eachRow( "select * from table" ) {
     doSometething it
   }
   db.close()
 }
```