# How can I do this query in Grails?

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have two domain classes:

```
class User {
    String nickname
}
```

and

```
class Episodes {
    String name
    User sentBy
}
```

I want to make a Ranking about who has sent more episodes.

So I did this query, and gives me the result that I want.

```
SELECT user.nickname, count(episodes.id) total
FROM user
JOIN episodes on user.id = episodes.sent_by
GROUP BY user.nickname
ORDER BY total DESC
```

What's the best way to run this query in my Controller? How?

Comment: That shouldn't be run in your controller, it should go in a service.

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Comment: @doelleri - Queries are fine in controllers, but updates should be transactional and in a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use HQL for this:

```
def results = User.executeQuery(
   'SELECT e.sentBy.nickname, count(e) as total ' +
   'FROM Episodes e ' +
   'GROUP BY e.sentBy.nickname ' +
   'ORDER BY total desc')
```

The result will be a list of Object[] arrays, with the 1st element being the nickname and the 2nd being the count, e.g.

```
for (Object[] row in results) {
   println "User ${row[0]} has ${row[1]} episodes"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is an answered question about your concern:

[Using groupProperty and countDistinct in Grails Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720060/using-groupproperty-and-countdistinct-in-grails-criteria)